# loading SQL onto database from eclipse IDE

Tags: sql, eclipse, oracle

I'm using Eclipse Helios with Subversive, Mylyn and Groovy plugins on Linux.
My repositories contain both java and Oracle PLSQL code.
(This works well for making code changes as my Mylyn contexts contain everything changed for a bug or feature addition)
Obviously when I change java code I can compile and run JUnit from within the IDE.
However if I change the PLSQL code I find myself switching to the command line and having to cat the .pls file through sqlplus to a database connection to test whether it compiles or not.

Is there a way of doing this from within the IDE and not having to switch to the command line ?

I already have a separate ant build script for the entire stored procedure directory which can deploy everything onto a reference database.

Any opinions very much appreciated
Rgds
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Toad extension for Eclipse](http://www.quest.com/toad-extension-for-eclipse/) to validate your PL/SQL code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this (Toad is not available on Linux) however I don't need a PLSQL syntax checker I need something that will load the PLSQL onto a specified database - does this plugin do that ? Also is it free ?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it as a tool similar to SQL developer from Oracle. Have a look at the feature list, especially http://toadextensions.com/pageloader.jspa?sbinPageName=EclipseFeatures.htm#worksheet